# RSA encoding and decoding [e,d]. Finding e and d in python.. Update

Tags: python, performance, cryptography, rsa, infinite-loop

I have been trying to find the encoding number and the decoding one. I know the basic rules which you need to find these and have started trying to create a python program which finds the e variable and d variable from a random choice of the first 150 primes. The way I did so was:

```
import random
from primesieve import *
from sympy.solvers import *
from sympy import *
f = 0
choiceOfPrimes = generate_primes(10)

p = random.choice(choiceOfPrimes)
q = random.choice(choiceOfPrimes)

while p == q:
    p = random.choice(choiceOfPrimes)

n = p * q
phiN = (p-1) * (q-1)
lista = []
listb = []
for naa in range(1, phiN):
    lista.append(naa)
for naaa in range(1, 35):
    listb.append(naaa)

e = random.choice(lista)


def finding_d():
    global phiN
    global e
    global f
    f = e
    abc = []
    abc = divmod(phiN, f)
    abc1 = f * abc[0]
    abc2 = abc[1]
    phiN = f * abc1 + abc2  # phiN = f * {how many it goes in} + {remainder}
    abc3 = divmod(f, abc2)
    f = abc2 * abc3[0] + abc3[1]  # (moved f to phiN) and (remainder to f)
    abc4 = divmod(abc2, abc3[1])
    e1 = abc3[1] * abc4[0]
    e2 = abc4[1]
    abc2 = e1 + e2
    e3 = abc2 + (e1*-1) # This bit I am struggling





d = f


while (e % n) == 0 and (e % phiN) == 0:
    for r in range(phiN, 0, -1):
        e = r

while ((d * e) % phiN) != 1:
    for r in range(1, 35):
        e = r

print(p, q, n, phiN, e, d)
```

which took forever to run and never completed running. I even tried changing the generate_primes(150) to generate_primes(10) but same problem occured.

Does anyone have a solution as I would be glad to hear it (btw the primesieve library isn't automatically in the python libraries, you'll have to download it yourself). Thanks.

EDIT:

I have done the:
    while p == q:
        p = random.choice(choiceOfPrimes)
but am having a difficult time of doing the euclidean mat

Comment: Sidenote: the `random` module in python in **not suitable for cryptography**

Comment: So, where did it get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of problems with your code :

Firstly,

```
while p == q:
   p = random.choice(choiceOfPrimes)
```

> You should do this step before calculating the value of `phiN` as the value of phiN would change if you change the value of `p`.

---

Secondly,

```
d = random.choice(lista)
```

> For calculating `d` you should find the [Modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of `e` with respect to `phiN` using the `Extended Euclidean algorithm`, choosing values of `e` untill they work is very inefficient.

Comment: How would I implement the Euclidean algorithm ?

Comment: There is an simple implementation of modular inverse on Rosetta Code : https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Modular_inverse#Python.

Comment: Now the value of `d` can be calculated using `modinv(e, phiN)` from the above code.